# Asmx webmethod doesn't send response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, apache-flex, asmx

I've got a .net 2 (ASMX) Webservice for an Adobe Flex client. The majority of service methods return XML and all work fine, however my `SaveChanges()` method accepts Xml to return a boolean. Whenever this method is called it only returns the 100-Continue header to the client and no result, Flex waits (presumably for a timeout) then thinks it's failed and starts up the error handlers.

Breakpoints in the service reveal the 100-Continue message is sent before the service method's body is reached (as expected), the method then gets to the return statement just fine but then no further response is received by the client.

I've setup [Membrane](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-monitor/) to sniff soap messages between the client and service and it can't see a response from the service either, but also can't see an added "Expects: 100-Continue" in the request that seems to be reported allot.

**EDIT :**

1. What could prevent the response message being sent after the return statement is reached?
2. I don't notice an 100-continue message from any other service method, from what I read this is HTTP saying "please wait for the actual result". Is there some way to disable this in the service and simply send the result?

**Service Method:**

```
[WebMethod]
public bool saveTemplateChanges( int id, string planTitle, string xml )
{
    using ( var spd = SeatPlanDb.Connect() ) // <= HTTP/1.1 100 CONTINUE is sent before this breakpoint
    {
        var templateChangesXml = this.CalculateDifferences( id, xml, "template" );
        spd.UpdateTemplateXml( templateChangesXml );
        spd.RunTemplateSeatplanFixups( id, planTitle );
    }

    return ( true ); // <= breakpoint reached
}
```

**Request:**

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58357
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/saveTemplateChanges"
Content-length: 12073
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tns:saveTemplateChanges xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <tns:id>100249</tns:id>
      <tns:planTitle>untitled</tns:planTitle>
      <tns:xml><performance ID="100249"><!-- Valid XML --></performance></tns:xml>
    </tns:saveTemplateChanges>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you try to call `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` in your `Application_Start`? Not sure if this helps but it is worth to try.

Comment: I've added this property but sadly didn't see any change, I think this would only affect messages sent via ASP.Net as opposed to the Flex client and the sniffed messages don't contain the `Expects: 100-continue` header.